# Factor analysis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, factor-analysis

I tried to perform a factor analysis with two significant factors.

```
[Lambda, Psi] = factoran(R,2,'xtype','covariance')
```

where matrix **R** is a 4x4 pairwise correlation matrix. Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Error using factoran (line 139)
The number of factors requested, M, is too large for the number of the observed
variables.
```

Why do I get the error and how I can walk around to find factor loadings?

Comment: Seems a matlab-specific question, vote to close

Answer (score 0):

Your correlation matrix should be at least 5x5.

Comment: However I found some examples in literature where authors perform a factor analysis on a 4x4 matrix with two significant factors. I wonder why matlab prohibits me from doing this?

Comment: Then is it impossible to solve the problem or just matlab can't do this? For instance here http://ifasstat.ifas.ufl.edu/sta4702/Pdf/Lecture05.pdf (on page 3) is an example of my problem that is solved (probably analytically).